# Is something wrong with @STRING processing between Jabref and biber?

Tags: biber, jabref

I've just been revisiting bibliographies, and trying to manage them with Jabref.
I seem to have found something wrong with `@string`s (or my understanding of them).
In my pre-Jabref `.bib` file, I have:

```
@string{pok = "Poughkeepsie, NY"}
@Manual{dxcapa24,
  ...
  location    = pok,
  ...
}
```

which in my `.bbl` file becomes, by courtesy of biber and BibLaTeX,

```
\list{location}{1}{%
  {Poughkeepsie, NY}%
  }
```

Now, after Jabref, my `.bib` file looks like this:

```
@STRING{pok = {Poughkeepsie, NY}}
@MANUAL{dxcapa24,
  ...
  location = {#pok#},
  ...
}
```

which fails to expand correctly in my `.bbl` file, causing a LaTeX error when it gets imbedded:

```
\list{location}{1}{%
    {#pok#}%
    }
```

My questions are:

- Am I doing something wrong and if so, how do I correct it?
- Where is the definitive `@string` syntax and semantics reference for `.bib` files?
- Is there a problem with Jabref and/or biber?

**Note:** I haven't provided a full MWE, as I believe the snippets fully illustrate the problem; but I'll be happy to provide one if the snippets are thought inadequate.

---

**Update:**

From the [BibTeX website:](http://www.bibtex.org/Format/)

> When quotation-marks are used, string concatenation using # is
>   possible, but not when braces are used.

Which *suggests* that Jabref might be in error. A view has also been exposed in the SF Jabref forums that Jabref itself should convert @strings to their expanded values, with another, Jabref-specific, mechanism for handling abbreviations which removes the need for `biber` to do this. Not sure I'm entirely happy with that, though.

---

Thanks to @Fran for reminding me: in my case, 
`shorttitle` is also messed up, while `author`, `title`, and `publisher` are handled correctly.

---

@Fran's answer solves the problem. I apologise for any premature aspersions on Jabref.

Comment: It should be `location=pok`, AFAIK. If JabRef writes out `location={#pok#}` then it's doing an utterly wrong thing. BibTeX doesn't do string substitutions in braced (or doubly quoted) fields and I believe Biber is the same.

Comment: @egreg : That was rather what I felt, though I was a bit hesitant to call *bug* on jabref.

Comment: Seem a problem with field `location` only: in `address` or `editor` fields the entry #pok# is saved correctly as `pok` without {}.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In  menu `Options` -> `Preferences` -> `File`  ->

Select the radio button "**Resolve strings for all fields except:**" instead of "Resolve strings for standard BibTeX fields only".